# When using method to control Master page : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, exception, master-pages

I'm a beginner at ASP.net, and want to create a class file that contains common used methods across my application. Like the one here that hides certain `ButtonLink`'s in the `login.aspx` and `registration.aspx` pages.

But when i start either one of these pages i get this error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here's my code :

`Helper.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Helper : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void hideLinks(){
            // error is produced at the following line at the start of
            // login.aspx or registration.aspx pages.
            LinkButton profile = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            LinkButton logout = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkButton2");

            profile.Visible = false;
            logout.Visible = false;
        }        
    }
}
```

`login.aspx.cs` & `registration.aspx.cs`:

```
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //LinkButton profile = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkButton1");
   //LinkButton logout = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkButton2");

   //profile.Visible = false;
   //logout.Visible = false;
   Helper master_helper = new Helper();
   master_helper.hideLinks();
}
```

Comment: try inherting your `Login.aspx.cs` page class with `Helper` class, and then simply use `Page.FindControl`, after you inherit.. You will not be making the object of Helper class instead you will write `base.hideLinks()`

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Hmmm `Login.aspx.cs` class already inherit `System.Web.UI.Page` class, so to inherit `Helper` class too should i use an Interface ?

Comment: No, you don't need to inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`, just inherit with `Helper` class and `Helper` class should inherit with `System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: Eh, I think this flies in the face of inheritance. A "login page" is _not_ a `Helper`. At the very least, rename it to something like `MyProjectPageBase` that all pages use, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating a new `Helper` (that is, a new `System.Web.UI.Page`) doesn't exist as part of the full page request so it doesn't have a reference to the same `Master` (if it even has one at all). Instead, redesign your `Helper` to take a `Master` (or the `Page`) in:

```
public class Helper
{
    private Page AssociatedPage;

    public Helper(Page page)
    {
        this.AssociatedPage = page;
    }

    public void hideLinks(){
        // error is produced at the following line at the start of
        // login.aspx or registration.aspx pages.
        LinkButton profile = (LinkButton)AssociatedPage.Master.FindControl("LinkButton1");
        LinkButton logout = (LinkButton)AssociatedPage.Master.FindControl("LinkButton2");

        profile.Visible = false;
        logout.Visible = false;
    }        
}
```

Then your usage might look like:

```
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Helper master_helper = new Helper(this);
   master_helper.hideLinks();
}
```

You could also redesign the method to be static and simply pass in the `Page` (or `Master`) reference in with the `hideLinks` method as an argument, but this is up to you.